# Synchronizing Socket.IO calls across multiple clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, network-programming, multiplayer

I'm pretty new to Javascript, Node, socket.io, and multiplayer game development in general, so I apologize in advance for anything obvious that I missed.

I have a node.js server that, when a browser goes to a particular website, creates a socket.io connection with that user. The server-side code receives any messages from a player and forwards it to whatever other players need that message

I'm trying to synchronize function calls across different browsers, so that they're called at as close to the same time as possible.

The expected workflow:

1. Player 1 sends a message that commands players 2 and 3 to run a function at the same time (in this case, a Countdown) as soon as possible
2. The server receives the message and sends it to Players 2 and 3
3. Players 2 and 3 both receive the message and start the countdown at the same time (or as close to the same time as possible)

Is there a standard way to synchronize calls like this across different socket connections?

Comment: Thats not how it works. Getting multiplayer games done over the TCP connections requires a lot of client side prediction, interpolation etc. There are lots of things to consider, lag, client computer performance. It different for the style of game you are making. This question is too broad to be answered.

Comment: send a timestamp with the command, the time that the command is to happen. but allowing the # of ms equal to the worst lag, you can deliver and  queue them in time for all to fire at the same moment. otherwise, you'll need to compensate for timing diffs in the game code.

Comment: @magreenberg I understand that standard multiplayer networking requires a lot more info than I am asking for, and I've already done some work on interpolation and handling lag, but that is beyond the scope of my question.

The only communication or synchronization that is needed right now is for a single function to be called at the same time on all clients (I.E. The StartGameCountdown function needs to be called). 

I can think of a few different ways to achieve this. I'm just wondering if there's some industry standard that I haven't found in my investigations.